# How to reference previous entries in a column while building with for loop in R?

Tags: r, recursion

In R:: I'm trying to create a new column in a data frame with a for loop that references the previous row in the same column. I am returned an error message that reads "replacement has length zero."

I have tried using the "reduce" and " filter" functions.

```
df$STATUS <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$STATUS[i] <- ifelse(df$start[i]==1 | ((df$STATUS[i-1])==1 & df$stop[i]==0), 1, 0)
}
```

I expected this code to fill the STATUS column according to the if statement nested in the for loop. The STATUS column is intended to write a 1 when start =1, and remain 1 until stop = 1. Instead, I received the error message:

> Error in
>              df$STATUS <- ifelse(df$start[i] == 1 | ((df$STATUS[i - :
>           replacement has length zero

Comment: You should assign a non-NA value for `df$STATUS[1]` and then start the loop from 2, i.e. `for(i in 2:nrow(df))`. When you start it from 1, there is no `df$STATUS[i-1]`, so you get an error.

Comment: This solved the problem- thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yannis mentioned, assign a non-NA value for df$STATUS[1] and ten star the loop from 2.

```
df <- data.frame(start = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), stop = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))

df$STATUS <- 0 #THIS GIVES ALL VALUES OF STATUS, INCLUDING ROW 1 THE VALUE 0

print(df)

#  start  stop STATUS
#     1     0      0
#     1     1      0
#     0     1      0
#     0     0      0
#     1     1      0
#     1     0      0
#     0     1      0
#     0     0      0

for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  df$STATUS[i] <- ifelse(df$start[i]==1 | ((df$STATUS[i-1])==1 & 
      df$stop[i]==0), 1, 0)

}

print(df)
#  start  stop STATUS
#     1     0      0
#     1     1      1
#     0     1      0
#     0     0      0
#     1     1      1
#     1     0      1
#     0     1      0
#     0     0      0
```